# Laravel sort object by Key

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

I have the following which I would like to order alphabetically by the Key i.e first for each array group would be "bname", followed by "created_at".

```
{
    "leads": [
        {
            "lead_id": 1,
            "zoho_lead": null,
            "bname": "ABC Limited",
            "tname": "ABC",
            "source_id": 11,
            "industry_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2017-09-06 15:54:21",
            "updated_at": "2017-09-06 15:54:21",
            "user": "Sean McCabe",
            "source": "Unknown",
            "industry": "None"
        },
        {
            "lead_id": 2,
            "zoho_lead": 51186111981,
            "bname": "Business Name Limited",
            "tname": "Trading Name",
            "source_id": 11,
            "industry_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2017-06-01 12:34:56",
            "updated_at": null,
            "user": "John Doe",
            "source": "Unknown",
            "industry": "None"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to use ksort like so in the foreach loop:

```
class LeadController extends Controller
{
    use Helpers;

    public function index(Lead $leads)
    {
        $leads = $leads->all();

        foreach($leads as $key => $lead){
            $lead->user = User::where('id', $lead->user_id)->first()->name;
            $lead->source = Source::where('id', $lead->source_id)->first()->name;
            $lead->industry = Industry::where('id', $lead->industry_id)->first()->name;

            $lead->ksort();
        }

        return $leads;
    }
```

But I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::ksort()
```

How do I use this function, or is there a Laravel way of doing this, or a better way altogether?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) By **what** *"Key"*? 2) Where is this data coming from? What is `$lead`? How is it assigned a value?

Comment: @Phil see edit with clarifications

Comment: The order of object keys should not make any difference to your data structure. Why does it matter?

Comment: Personally I don't care what order they come out in, as I can call each by name, but I have been asked to have them output in alphabetical order.

Comment: Obviously `$leads->all()` is returning a [traversable](http://php.net/manual/class.traversable.php) collection of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` objects whereas you seem to expect them to be something else with a `ksort` method. You should probably work out why that is the case

Comment: just curious why do you need to sort data ? its a collection you can use it however you want

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, do you have relationships set up in your `Lead` model for `User`, `Source` and `Industry`?

Comment: @RossWilson yes i do. i.e. in Lead.php Model
public function user()
{
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class);      
 }

Answer (score 2):

Managed to get it to return with the Keys in alphabetical order, so below is the solution in-case someone else should require it:

```
public function index(Lead $leads)
{
    $leadOut = Array();

    $leads = $leads->all();

    foreach($leads as $key => $lead){
        $lead->user = User::where('id', $lead->user_id)->first()->name;
        $lead->source = Source::where('id', $lead->source_id)->first()->name;
        $lead->industry = Industry::where('id', $lead->industry_id)->first()->name;

        //Convert to Array
        $leadOrder = $lead->toArray();
        //Sort as desired
        ksort($leadOrder);
        //Add to array
        $leadOut[] = $leadOrder;
    }

    return $leadOut;
}
```

There is likely a cleaner way to do this, but it works for my instance, and perhaps additional answers may be posted that are better.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
return Lead::with('user', 'source', 'industry')->get()->map(function ($lead) {

        $item = $lead->toArray();

        $item['user'] = $lead->user->name;
        $item['source'] = $lead->source->name;
        $item['industry'] = $lead->industry->name;

        ksort($item);

        return $item;
    });
```

This should be much more efficient as it will eager load the relationships rather than make 3 extra queries for each iteration.

Comment: I get the error:  "Illegal offset type in isset or empty"

Comment: @SeánMcCabe What version of PHP are you using and what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: 5.6.31 and 5.4. I've managed to solve the whole issue now using Fractal, allows me to output the stuff in the order that has been requested and change the names for security.
Controller now just has the two lines
$leads = Lead::with('user', 'source', 'industry', 'status')->get();
return fractal($leads, new LeadTransformer())->respond();